# Programming environment : Managing windows and monitors on a Mac

Tags: macos, development-environment

What is a good way to "snap" windows into position into multiple monitors? I used to use ultramon on windows. These days, it is pain to manage windows individually, especially with the fact that resizing can only happen on the bottom left.

Curious to know what programs and tips everyone has. Thanks!

Comment: You will likely get a better response if you ask your question over at http://superuser.com/. You've used the 'programming' tag, but the question actually has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want a tiling window manager: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276760/tiling-window-manager-for-mac-os-x